# How does the fragment shader get data from the vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, lwjgl, graphics-programming

How can any interactions between these two shaders work? I mean the vertex shader sends a vertex's color to the fragment shader, but that's only one fragment, what about all the other ones between the vertices?

Does the fragment shader get called a lot more than the vertex shader?

I mean the fragment-to-vertex ratio is pretty high in most games, given that a fragment is a pixel, right?

Comment: If you're curious about the actual mechanisms of *how* the hardware interpolates values, see here: http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-7/ .... Note that there are actually several different interpolation modes -- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29 -- flat, noperspective, smooth, centroid, and sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertex shaders gets called a lot less than fragment shaders. It's because the fragments get generated from the vertices with a process that is called rasterization. Rasterization basically generates fragments using the triangle's corners and give each fragment an interpolated value using the values in the vertices, produced by a vertex shader.

Let's say that you have a triangle `ABC` like this:

```
a = 0,0,0 
b = 1,0,0 
c = 1,1,0
```

Depending on the resolution, this generates some amount of fragments covering the whole triangle.

This will produce a triangle which covers half of the screen, which at 1920x1200 resolution will be `1920*1200/2` fragments. The amount of fragments increase with every triangle you draw.

[A fragment is not a pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader#Simplified_graphic_processing_unit_pipeline). It is much more.

Comment: I mean, if I say
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
it makes all fragments between vertices red.
Then why
gl_FragColor = vColor;
where vColor is the vertex shader's passed vertex color,
make a nice gradient between vertices?

Comment: I edited. Does it now answer your question?

Comment: Oh so, the vertex color stays the same and is applied to all fragments, just it also gets interpolated with other colors to make the gradient?

Comment: The colour of the vertex stays the same, and the colour of the fragments is got from interpolating the colour of the vertices. http://doc.minko.io/wiki/Understanding_vertex_to_fragment_interpolation

Comment: @Lasse why would it be twice the amount of fragments without backface culling? You only render one triangle. If it faces the wrong direction there will be 0 fragments generated. The rasterization pipeline doesn't generate two fragments for each rasterized point of a triangle without backface culling.

Comment: @TravisG You are correct. I got that mistaken with drawing 3d shapes with overlaping triangles. I will edit the answer.